# Calculate vector potential $\vec{A}$ induced by current through conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I want to calculate the magnetic vector potential $\vec{A}$ at $P$. If I know how to do this for one side, I know how to do it for every side. So lets just stick with the leftmost side only. Lets start with Biot-savart's law:

$$\vec{A}=\frac{\mu_0 i}{4\pi}\oint_C\frac{d\vec{\ell}}{R}. \tag1$$

We know that $$d\vec{\ell}=-dy \ \hat{y} \tag2$$ and $R$ is the distance between our infinitesimal piece of wire $d\vec{\ell}$ and the point $P$ which is

$$R=\sqrt{x^2+(a-y)^2}.\tag3$$

Putting everything together we obtain

$$\vec{A}=-\frac{\mu_0 i}{4\pi}\int_a^0\frac{dy}{\sqrt{x^2+(a-y)^2}} \ \hat{y} = \frac{\mu_0 i}{4\pi} \ \ln\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}-a}\right).$$

But according to professors note the answer is

$$\vec{A}=\frac{\mu_0i}{4\pi} \ \ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+y}{\sqrt{(a-y)^2+x^2}-a+y}\right).$$

Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: The distances to P are different for each line

Comment: You calculate the integral over a closed loop. It should be 4 integrals for 4 sides of the contour.

Comment: @BrunoAnghinoni, yes that's why I integrate over $y$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev - I know it should be 4 integrals, but I just need to do one in order to know how to do the others. Both answers above only represent the $\vec{A}$ given by the left side.

Comment: For the right line, for example, the distance in $x$ is not just $x$ as in the integral you showed, but $\sqrt{(x-a)^2}$. This would give a different result. I recommend you perform the 4 integrals separately and then sum then. It should work.

Comment: @BrunoAnghinoni - I'm not sure you have read the beginning of my post. I clearly state that I ONLY want to calculate the $\vec{B}-$field generated by the leftmost side. And according to the notes for the left side, my answer is wrong and I'm wondering where my mistake is.

Comment: The integral from ${0}$ to ${a}$ may not be symmetrical about a horizontal line passing through $(x_{p},y_{p})$ - which is implied by your integral. The angle between the wire and $R$ below $(x_{p},y_{p})$ appears to be different from the angle between the wire and $R$ above $(x_{p},y_{p})$. I'm assuming the horizontal line through $(x_{p},y_{p})$ is not the line $y=a/2$.

Comment: I would argue you need to break up the integral into: $\int_{0}^{y}\frac{dl}{\sqrt{(a-x)^{2}+l^{2}}} + \int_{a-y}^{a}\frac{dl}{\sqrt{(a-x)^{2}+l^{2}}}$ where $dl$ is the integral along the wire from $(0,a)$ to $(a,a)$.